# Can't access an object's methods from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, object

Java tells me it can't find getName() when i try to run the main method. I'm not sure why, I've looked around stackexchange to no avail. It seems like such a simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayTester
{
    public static ArrayList<Object> array;

    public static void main(String args[])
{
        array = new ArrayList<Object>();
        array.add(new TestObject("Some Name"));
        System.out.println("Object Name: " + array.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

Object:

```
public class TestObject
{
    private String name;

    public TestObject(String cname){
        name = cname;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help in advance. I apologize if there is an identical question somewhere that I didn't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Java tells me it can't find getName() when i try to run the main
>   method

Cast `Object` class to `TestObject` class to use the methods of `TestObject` class. Since `array.get(0)` returns `Object` class as object. There is no such method means `getName()` exists in `Object` class.

change

```
System.out.println("Object Name: " + array.get(0).getName());
```

to

```
System.out.println("Object Name: " + ((TestObject)array.get(0)).getName());
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. I hadn't thought about needing to cast it this way.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to store different type of objects in the ArrayList, you should find out, what is common in these. For example all of these have a name. Then you can create an interface, called TestInterface:

```
public interface TestInterface {

     String getName();
}
```

The interface defines the getName() method and all the classes which implement it, contains the getName(), too.

The TestClass should implement the TestInterface:

```
public class TestObject implements TestInterface {

     private String name;

     public TestObject(String cname) {
         name = cname;
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }
 }
```

You can also write an OtherClass:

```
public class OtherClass implements TestInterface {

     public String getName() {
         return "OtherClass getName method";
     }
}
```

Your main:

```
public class ArrayTester {
     public static ArrayList<TestInterface> array;

     public static void main(String args[]) {
          array = new ArrayList<TestInterface>();
          array.add(new TestObject("Some Name"));
          array.add(new OtherClass());
          for (TestInterface t: array) {
               System.out.println("Object Name: " + t.getName());
          }
     }
}
```

You can pass instances of all classes which implement TestInterface to the ArrayList and when you iterate over it, Java call the concrete implementations of the getName() method.

The output:

```
Some Name
OtherCalss getName method
```

Cast can also work, but it isn't type safe. In the ArrayList of Object type you can pass all kinds of object. It is also OK, when you pass a String to it. It compiles, but when you try to cast the String to TestObject, you will have a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 1):

You created a class named `TestObject`, so you should create array with `TestObject`, not `Object`:

```
public class ArrayTester
{
    public static ArrayList<TestObject> array;

    public static void main(String args[])
{
        array = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
        array.add(new TestObject("Some Name"));
        System.out.println("Object Name: " + array.get(0).getName());
    }
}
```

or at least cast it:

```
System.out.println("Object Name: " + ((TestObject) array.get(0).getName());
```

Comment: While true, I wanted to create an arraylist that could accept different kinds of objects, not just TestObjects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **instanceof** function and compare it in **if** block before appropriate casting :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String name;
    array = new ArrayList<Object>();
    array.add(new TestObject("Some Name"));
    for (Object o : array) {
        if(o instanceof TestObject){
            System.out.println("Object Name: " + ((TestObject) o).getName());
        } 
    }
}
```

and of o is instance of some other class you can simple compare it in if block and call corresponding function after casting like :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String name;
    array = new ArrayList<Object>();
    array.add(new TestObject("Some Name"));
    for (Object o : array) {
        if(o instanceof TestObject){
            System.out.println("Object Name: " + ((TestObject) o).getName());
        } 
        else if(o instanceof SomeObject){
            System.out.println("Object Name: " + ((SomeObject) o).getSomeObjectFunction());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will solve your problem.